# Transform continious date string (20190327200000000W) in date time

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I'm doing an application which parse a XML from http request and one of the attributes is a date.
The problem is that the format is a string without separation, for example: '20190327200000000W' and I need to transform it into a datetime format to send it to a database.
All the information I have found is with some kind of separation char (2019-03-23 ...). Can you help me?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you know what it is *supposed* to represent? `strptime` can probably handle it, but it's not clear how to interpret it. My guess would be `2019-03-27 20:00:00 000W`, but I don't know if that trailing `000W` is supposed to be milliseconds, or a timezone, or what.

Comment: I'm not sure, I only know that the documentation that I have said that it's a "extended format = “YYYYMMDDHHMNSSFFFX”". I think that I'm only need YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-sss but if the datetime format of the database accept all the format I'll send all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this? (in jupypter notebook)

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('20190327200000000W', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%fW')
datetime_object
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have solved this, at first I did that Xenobiologist said, but I had a format problem, so I decided to delete the last character (the X of %X)...and I realized that I hadn't a string, I had a list, so I transformed to string and did the operations. My code (I'll put only the inside for loop part, without the parsing part):

```
 for parse in tree.iter(aaa):
            a = parse.get(m)
            respon = a.split(' ')
            if m == 'Fh':

                x = str(respon[0])
                x2 = len(x)
                x3 = x[:x2-1]
                print (x3)
                y = time.strptime(x3, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")
```